# Constraining a choice of vector from a given space

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have a hyperplane equation:

$$\vec{x}\cdot \vec{w} = 0$$

Now, on its own, this just means that $\vec{x} \in Nullspace(\vec{w})$.  I have additional constraints on the components of $\vec{x}$, specifically:

$$\sqrt{1-x_i^2} = K + x_i, K\in\mathbb{R}, x_i \in [-1,1]$$

How do I restrict my choice of $\vec{x}$ in the first equation so that it satifies the constraint equations?  $\vec{w}$ is known, as is K, but I can't seem to figure out how to intersect the constraints with the null space.

Comment: Your constraints imply that $x_i=\frac12(-K\pm\sqrt{2-K^2})$, so there are only two choices for each $x_i$, and thus if $x\in\mathbb R^n$ there are only $2^n$ feasible values $x$ can take...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure this is what you exactly need, but I guess the following analysis may be helpful.*

First of all, $\sqrt{1 - x_i^2} \in [0,1]$ then $K \in [0,1]$. Then, supposing $K + x_i \geq 0$, from condition $\sqrt{1 - x_i^2} = K + x_i$ we get $1 - x_i^2 = (K + x_i)^2$ which leads to $$\left(x_i + \frac{K}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{K^2}{4}$$
(note that right part is positive as $K \in [0,1]$). Let $n$ be a dimension of space containing $\vec{x}$. Then we may sum this equation for $i = 1,\dots, n$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i + \frac{K}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{nK^2}{4}.$$
Let $\vec{K}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with components $K_i = K/2$. Then we may rewrite it as
$$\left|\left|\vec{x} + \vec{K}\right|\right|^2 = R^2,$$
where $R^2 = n/2 - ||\vec{K}||^2$,  so $\vec{x}$ is a point of sphere with center in $-\vec{K}$ and radius $R$.

We also should remember about condition $K + x_i > 0$. This condition has no such clear geometric interpretation and may be represented as system of $n$ inequalities like $(\vec{x} + 2\vec{K})\cdot \vec{e}_i > 0$, where $\vec{e}_i$ is $i$-th ort.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Now, the more general problem has all of the constraint equations with a different, known $K$.  I'll try working through the problem with this general condition according to your work.  I suspect that using the vector notation for K will help, and possibly we can just bound it.  If you have any thoughts on the general problem I'd be happy to hear them :-)

Comment: Oh, I've answered my own comment with just a bit more algebra: if the $K_i$ are not all the same, the vector $\vec{K}$ has components $K_i/2$, but the radius equation $R^2 = n/2 - ||\vec{K}||^2$ still holds, so the interpretation is the same, the radius is just different.  I believe that is correct.  So, that being the case, the problem actually reduces to intersecting a hypersphere with a hyperplane.  That sounds like it's already been solved somewhere...hopefully :-P